# How to sum over multiple fields in an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a charges model that contain Price And Quantity , i want to multiply Price and Quantity and sum the results and update a table named bill with final results , here is my array

```
 [
  [
    "Title" => "Price 1",
    "Quantity" => "1",
    "Price" => "1",
  ],
  [
    "Title" => "Price 2",
    "Quantity" => "232",
    "Price" => "32632",
  ],
  [
    "Title" => "Price 3",
    "Quantity" => "11",
    "Price" => "2115",
  ],
]
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? Have you tried doing it "manually" by iterating over this array? 

I am not sure where your problem begins.

Comment: i dont know ho to it , to explain the problem i have a dinamic form with multiple fields , and t store the fields in an $charges array wich i need to multiply the price and quantity in order to update bill table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$billItems` is your initial array, you can do this in one line:

```
$grandTotal = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { return $item['Quantity'] * $item['Price']; }, $billItems));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections like this

$collection->sum('Price');

or

```
$yourArray = [
        [
            "Title" => "Price 1",
            "Quantity" => "1",
            "Price" => "1",
        ],
        [
            "Title" => "Price 2",
            "Quantity" => "232",
            "Price" => "32632",
        ],
        [
            "Title" => "Price 3",
            "Quantity" => "11",
            "Price" => "2115",
        ]
    ];  

$collection = collect($yourArray);

$payment = $collection->sum(function ($item) {
    $item['Price'] = $item['Price'] * $item['Quantity'];
    return $item['Price'];
});

dd($payment); // 7593890
```

more https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sum

Comment: how to multiply Price And Quantity  before using sum

Comment: $addition = $addition ->each(function ($item, $key) { // add new property $item['val'] = price * qty });

Comment: $add = $add ->each(function ($item, $key) { // add new property $item['val'] = price * qty }); 
$collection->sum($add );
like that ?

Comment: Should return 7593890 ( (1*1)+(232*32632)+(11*2115) )

Comment: Do You try it? ;-)